# how to take user input in livesql.oracle.com in PLSQL

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, oracle18c

How to take user input in Oracle 18c in online Oracle Database ([livesql.oracle.com](https://livesql.oracle.com)) in PLSQL in Runtime.

Comment: From [the LiveSQL FAQs](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/f?p=590:HELP:115542990175435::NO:::) **"Q: Can I use input parameters?"** *"A: No, we do not support input parameters at runtime.*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you can't do that.

A workaround is to create a procedure with a parameter and pass its value that way. For example,

```
create or replace procedure p_disp(par_param in varchar2) is
begin
  dbms_output.put_line(par_param);
end;
/

begin
  p_disp('lf');
end;
/
```

---

However, if you meant to use that *parameter* in plain SQL, such as

```
select * From v$session where sid = :sid;

OR

select * From v$session where sid = &sid;
```

none of these works; you'd get `ORA-01008: not all variables bound` error.